# Collapsible Panel

Tags: winrt-xaml, uwp

Windows 10's Calendar app has a collapsible "expander" panel, though it doesn't seem to be part of the standard controls.  Is this available anywhere?  If not, what's the simplest way to implement this?

[image]

(This seems to have been asked here somewhere, though no answers were given as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 10 XAML Controls, there's no official Collapsible Panel in the list, but you can create your own control using custom control and some code.. Here's a full tutorial about how to create a expand control:

[Windows 10 Expand Control](https://comentsys.wordpress.com/2015/05/30/windows-10-universal-windows-platform-expand-control/)

*The tutorial is long, I can't provide a code/ XAML for that in the answer :).*

Comment: Saw that as well. Was hoping this is built-in, considering the use-case is fairly common. Thanks!